# How to connect 2 vertexes in an Adjacency List?

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn different Data Structures and I'm currently struggling on Graphs.

I am trying to implement an Adjacency List using a Map of Linked Lists. This lets me be able to search up the name of the vertex and see all its connections quickly.

But I am having trouble actually adding any connections. What I'm currently doing is

```
   public void add(V vertexName) {
    if (!contains(vertexName)) {
        ArrayList<V> array = new ArrayList<>(); 
        adjList.put(vertexName,array);
    }

}

public void connect(V start, V destination) {
if (!contains(start) || !contains(destination))
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
adjList.get(start).add(destination); //adds destination to starts arraylist

}

System.out.print(adjList.toString);
```

But, for example, if I add 12, 10, and 20 to my list and then connect 20 and 12, I still just get:

```
12

10

20
```

instead of

```
12

10

20 - > 12
```

Any tips would be much appreciated. If it helps, adjList is a

```
Map<V,ArrayList<V>> adjList;
```

And i'm just trying to start off with a directed unweighted Graph to make things easier

Comment: Are you sure it's not to do with how you're displaying it?

Comment: Shouldn't it print out correctly if I just simply print out each ArrayList using the toString method?

Comment: Better show your complete code, including initialisation and printing.

Comment: Can you show the code which prints unexpected result?

Comment: I've added all relevant code.

Comment: It is working correctly in my system. Don't know why you are not getting required result.